# why keytool generate 16 character string instead 28 character string - I want to generate Hash Key for Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, firebase-authentication, facebook-sdk-4.0, keytool

In my app there is a facebook login. I would like to add an Android app to my facebook app which needs a hash generated with the keytool from the keystore file.

if I run the command on my debug key, (which is the default android debug key) it only generates a 16 character long hash.

I use this command in windows' default cmd:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore >"C:\Users\myusernamehere.android\debug.keystore" | >"D:\Programs\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary >|"D:\Programs\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

https://photos.app.goo.gl/NPcsajE3A2yfxtox7

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by deleting the debug.keystore file.
Then first clean project from android studio and then again  rebuild the project.
From this it will generate again debug.keystore file.
So this time when you will run the command on cmd it will generate the 32 character long strings.